# Distributivity of tensor product over a direct sum

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, direct-sum

Let $\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{K}$ be finite dimensional Hilbert spaces and consider the space
$$\left(\mathcal{H} \oplus \mathcal{K}\right) \otimes L^2(\mathbb{R}).$$
I would like a reference to show that this is isomorphic to
$$\left(\mathcal{H} \otimes L^2(\mathbb{R})\right) \oplus \left(\mathcal{K} \otimes L^2(\mathbb{R})\right)$$
if it does indeed hold here. I've seen this result if all of the above were finite-dimensional vector spaces, but not for an infinite dimensional case, even though we have separability for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are stated in Atiyah-Macdonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* (pg 26) for general modules, assuming neither finite dimensionality (generation) nor that the underlying ring is a field.

Depending on your background, you could just check that the standard proof using the universal property goes through without any assumptions about finite-dimensionality.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I might check it myself too for a bit of fun ;-)